# If object reaches the edge of the canvas, open a new activity. How do I do this?

Tags: android, android-canvas

This code is from theNewBoston website by bucky tutorial 128. Please refer to it as needed.
https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=6&video=16849

If the green ball hits the edges of the canvas, I want it to open a new activity. How do I do write this process?

public class Accelerate extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

```
float x, y, sensorX, sensorY;
float alpha;
Bitmap ball;
SensorManager sm;
MyBringBackSurface ourSurfaceView;

public class MyBringBackSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    boolean isRunning = false;

    public MyBringBackSurface(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();

    }

    public void pause(){
        isRunning = false;
        while(true){
            try {
                ourThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        ourThread = null;
    }

    public void resume(){
        isRunning = true;
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(isRunning){
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            //canvas.drawRGB(2, 2, 100); blue
            canvas.drawRGB(227, 168, 105); //Mango peach
            //float centerX = canvas.getWidth()/2;
            //float centerY = canvas.getHeight()/2;

            float centerX = (canvas.getWidth()-ball.getWidth())/2;
            float centerY = (canvas.getHeight()-ball.getHeight())/2;

            canvas.drawBitmap(ball, centerX + sensorX*20, centerY + sensorY*20, null);
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);



        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() != 0){
        Sensor s = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.greenball);
    x = y = sensorX = sensorY = 0;
    ourSurfaceView = new MyBringBackSurface(this);
    ourSurfaceView.resume();
    setContentView(ourSurfaceView);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sm.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Thread.sleep(16);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    alpha = (float) 0.8;

    sensorX = alpha*sensorX + (1-alpha)*e.values[0];
    sensorY = alpha*sensorY + (1-alpha)*e.values[1];


    //sensorX = e.values[0];
    //sensorY = e.values[1];

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you are done computing and checking if the ball hits the edge of the canvas. you only need to get access of your activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(youmainactivity, yournewactivityclass.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

or if you have your context

```
Intent intent = new Intent((Activity) context,yournewactivityclass.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No, I also need to know how to check if the ball hits the edge.

Comment: i will be giving you what you need to do but not the code exactly. you need to get the position of the ball and check if it is 0(left edge of the phone) and y position minus height(bottom part of the phone). then if the position of the ball + the width is equals to the width of the phone(right edge of the phone)  y position of the ball is equals to height of the phone( top part of the phone)